# finding users latitudes and longitudes inside closed location

Tags: android, latitude-longitude

I have been working on an android app to find the location of the user device even he is in the closed location.

I am trying to use the following code:

```
LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
criteria.setAltitudeRequired(false);
criteria.setBearingRequired(false);
criteria.setCostAllowed(true);
criteria.setPowerRequirement(Criteria.POWER_LOW);
String provider = lm.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
Location location = lm.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
```

by using this code i was able to get the locations when i go to the open sky but not in the room.

please let me know how if any thing is unclear.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot get standard GPS while you are inside. If you own/control a particular building then you could set up some sort of transmitters inside of the building that would help you triangulate their position.  Otherwise, you are out of luck.

Comment: if not by the GPS is there are any way i can find the location of the device - Network, WiFi which the device is accessing ?

Comment: Not without knowing where those WiFi hot-spots are, already.  If you have a good enough connection, you may be able to get the "coarse location" through the cell towers but you get those coordinates using the same GPS API.

Comment: Using something other than `Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE` will help with getting cell-tower-based positioning.